# Create a click event using selenium when there are multiple same class and no id elements using Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to create an automated download event for one ERP platform using Selenium in python. This is a bit tricky for this part as there is no specific element to find and click.

Multiple buttons have the same class and no id for the **highlighted button (DATABASE/BACKUP)**

[image]

Can anyone help me with the same?

event flow >>
Login page > click "administration button" > click "database / backup"

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per Selenium documentation https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html you can find all of the elements by their class name and then access them by index ([index_number]).

```
all_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("your_class_name")
```

then you can do something like:

```
button_to_click = all_buttons[3] # The 4th button which has index 3 in all the retrieved buttons by class name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[contains(text(),'Database / Backup')]").click()
```

Simply click the a tag which contains the text.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **DATABASE/BACKUP** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='menui' and contains(., 'DATABASE/BACKUP')]").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[text()[contains(., 'DATABASE/BACKUP')]]").click()
  ```

---

The desired element is a dynamic element, ideally to click on a ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='menui' and contains(., 'DATABASE/BACKUP')]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()[contains(., 'DATABASE/BACKUP')]]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```